# Replace the value of attribute using mappings in another xml?

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery

I have the following mappings defined in Sql server.

```
declare @map xml = '<Maps><Map From="1" To="2"/><Map From="3" To="4" /></Maps>';
```

I will need to change the value of attribute `Id` following (examples) xml using the mapping. However, the root element can be anything and I want to keep all the other attributes.

```
declare @x xml;

set @x = '<XX><Value Id="1" OtherAttrs="..." /><Value Id="3" /></XX>';
-- Expect <XX><Value Id="2" OtherAttrs="..." /><Value Id="4" /></XX>

set @x = '<YY><Value Id="3" /><Value Id="1" OtherAttrs="..." /></YY>';
-- Expect <YY><Value Id="4" /><Value Id="2" OtherAttrs="..." /></YY>

select @x.query('...') -- How to write the xquery?
```

How to write the xquery script?

What if I have only two kinds of root element `<XX>` and `<YY>`?

Comment: It was a typo and I fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a hack, but consider the following

**Example**

```
declare @map xml = '<Maps><Map From="1" To="2"/><Map From="3" To="4" /></Maps>';

Declare @X xml = '<XX><Value Id="1" /><Value Id="3" /></XX>'

Select @X = Replace(cast(@X as varchar(max)),MapFrom,MapTo)
 From (
        Select MapFrom = 'Id="'+n.value('@From','varchar(max)')+'"'
              ,MapTo   = 'Id="'+n.value('@To'  ,'varchar(max)')+'"'
         From  @map.nodes('/Maps/*') as X(n)
      ) A

Select @X
```

**Returns**

```
<XX>
  <Value Id="2" />
  <Value Id="4" />
</XX>
```

**If it helps with the Visualization**

The subquery generates the following.

```
MapFrom   MapTo
Id="1"    Id="2"
Id="3"    Id="4"
```

You may notice I included the full string `{attribute name}="{value}"` this is to avoid collisions and overreach.